# MERN app by MongoDB missing recordList() function

Tags: mongodb, mern

I am learning how to create full-stack mern applications & I decided to follow the tutorial at this link https://www.mongodb.com/languages/mern-stack-tutorial

I am at this point: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpxrI.png)

which the last step, but I think there is a missing function called recordList() at recordList.js which is on the description of the tutorial. Has anyone done this tutorial? if you did you notice that it is uncomplete? or am I not seen something?

Alternativity if anyone has got any good sources where I can learn this topic , it'll be much appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide any info on what the error message is or what's not working? In the tutorial you can see that in _recordList.js_, inside the _RecordList_-Component there is the function _recordList()_ I assume this one is missing for you. If you provide more details we can help you better

Comment: hey @st.huber! Thank you for asking. It seems that when the tutorial was posted this method `recordList()` was not in the recordList.js file. Although it is there now - I think the tutorial got updated. Thanks!